# Rest API nonce is being cached

Tags: rest-api, cache, nonce

I'm building a custom Rest Api endpoint. User can call this endpoint via ajax request in the frontend together with nonce value which was created by

```
wp_localize_script( 'some-js', 'wpApiSettings', [
       'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ),
    ],
] );
```

The problem is the caching plugin. In my case, I've used breeze.

It cache the page together with nonce value. When the nonce is expired, the page cache still have the expired nonce in it. So when the used this nonce, they receive `rest_cookie_invalid_nonce` until the cached is cleared.

Is there a way to prevent this from happen?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the nonce to the script you can get the nonce using an ajax request. That way the script is cached, but each user gets a different nonce via the response. Just make sure the ajax response isn't being cached by your plugin.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_nonce', 'generate_nonce' );    
function generate_nonce(){
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce('my-nonce');
    echo $nonce;
    wp_die();
}
```

Then use something like this in your javascript.

```
var nonce;
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.get(ajaxurl+'?action=get_nonce', function(data){ 
        nonce = data;
    });
});
```